# UIScrollView Dome Effect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

DESIRED EFFECT:

Imagine a UIScrollView such that as you scroll in any direction, you feel like you're looking around inside a dome. As in, the screen is stretched/warped/distorted at the edges by a filter/mesh of some sort. Think of a 3D game where you're looking up at the sky.

WHAT IT'S FOR:

I plan on plastering menu items on a sky of sorts. Imagine looking at the sky where clouds are tappable menu items and there are enough clouds such that you have to scroll around to find them all. This is just a menu to the actual content; it isn't a full 3D game where you can move around and such. I am therefore hoping that I can fake the 3D effect by stretching/warping/distorting the edges of the screen.

WHAT I NEED:

I need to at least know the direction to look in so that I can see how feasible and how much work it will take. If it's too much, I'll unfortunately have to do something else.

From what I've looked at so far, it appears that QuartzCore isn't enough and I suspect that OpenGL is the only way to do it. Before I throw myself into OpenGL though (I'm a complete noob at it), I'd like to know if that's even the correct technology that I should be looking at. And if it is, what area of it I should be looking at (initial searches indicated stuff like texture warping might be what I'm looking for?).

Thanks!

Comment: you could probably do this in 10 minutes if you know your way around unity. Simply use NGUI for interface and then the iOS accelerometer feature to transform what the camera is looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re on the right track. You’ll want to use OpenGL ES for this. The basic idea behind this that I’ve seen used to great effect is to project the scene on the inside of a cube, rotating the cube when the user moves their finger. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741838) really helped me when I got started with OpenGL.